# Scrape data with HtmlAgilityPack for a tag which doesn't have class

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Here is my C# code what i am trying to do is to scrape data from a website by using HtmlAgilityPack but it's showing nothing found every time don't know what i am doing wrong a bit confused

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb webb = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = webb.Load("mywebsite");


        HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='unstyled']//li//a");

       if (nodes != null)
       {
           foreach (HtmlNode n in nodes)
           {
               q = n.InnerText;
               q = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(q);
               q = q.Trim();
               Console.WriteLine(q);
           }

       }
       else
       {
           Console.WriteLine("nothing found");
       }
```

[Here is the picture of the tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqZpX.png) from which i am trying to capture data i need data from `<a>` tag .

Comment: Can you try ul[@class='unstyled']/li/a as the selector?

Comment: i have tried that still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath used to select the  tag is incorrect.

```
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = 
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='unstyled']/li/a");
```

This should select all the anchor nodes and then you can loop through the nodes to get the InnerHtml.

Working sample shown below

```
string s = "<ul class='unstyle no-overflow'><li><ul class='unstyled'><li><a href='http://www.smsconnexion.com'>SMS ConneXion</a></li></ul><ul class='unstyled'><li><a href='http://www.celusion.com'>Celusion</a></li></ul></li></ul>";


HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(s);

HtmlNodeCollection nodes = 
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='unstyled']/li/a");

foreach(var node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["href"].Value);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I have tried this my friend i have also edit the question but it's still not working

Comment: @RAJASAHAB I have updated the answer with a working sample.

Comment: the data which i want is in <a href="whateverdata"></a> i know you can help me please

Comment: @RAJASAHAB so you want to extract the value /phone/1-201 from your example? If that is the case, I have updated the example to read the href attribute.

Comment: its working with the example string you give but when i am trying to load in the website it not working on website , can website restrict us to do that?

Comment: @RAJASAHAB I did not understand. Is this a public website. If yes, you can share the url here.

Comment: @RAJASAHAB The URL is preventing scraping.

Comment: isn't there anyway way to scrap data from this URL ??

Comment: isn't there anyway way to scrap data from this URL ??

Comment: As they do not allow it, I would advise not to attempt it.